# Simple PHP regular expression question

Tags: php, regex

What's the most efficient [preg_match](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) regular expression for the following:

1. The regular expression must match a certain string (case **insensitive**)
2. Can be followed by [ or ; **and then** something else

These are the test cases for "foo":

- foo           --> good
- food          --> bad
- foo;          --> bad, need something after ;
- FOO;bar       --> good
- foo[bar]      --> good
- foo[          --> bad, need something after ]
- fOo[bar]1;2;3 --> good

This is my test code:

```
<?php

$tests = array();
$tests[] = 'foo';
$tests[] = 'food';
$tests[] = 'foo;';
$tests[] = 'FOO;bar';
$tests[] = 'foo[bar]';
$tests[] = 'foo[';
$tests[] = 'foo[]';
$tests[] = 'fOo[bar]1;2;3';

foreach ($tests as $test)
{
    echo $test, ' --> ';
    $found = preg_match('REGULAR EXPRESSION HERE', $test);
    if ($found === false || $found < 1)
        echo 'bad';
    else
        echo 'ok';
    echo '<br>', PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading tutorials / information on regular expressions? Seems like a homework assignment and I would suggest actually reading and finding the answer on your own, it will help you out in the long run.

Comment: Idk about php syntax, but python would match foo([|;)(.*)

Comment: @premiso I've ended school 8 years ago (thank god), I know it's really simple, but I HATE regular expressions and try to avoid them as much as possible. I'm slowly learning them but still :) I still need to find a good site about them. All the one I have are overly complicated...

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ « This is a good site about regular expressions.

Comment: I see you've made a lot of questions on Regular Expressions, allow me to recommend you this: http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/

Comment: @Fernando Yeah I mostly ask questions about regular expressions here because I'm not well versed with them and need them like 5-10 times a year :) I have the time to forget every thing I learned about them between their use. Thanks for the book link!

Comment: @Activist I understand. Regular expressions are awesome though. Check out http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/10-reasons-to-learn-and-use-regular-expressions and please do check out this link: http://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex :

`/foo(;.+?|\[.+?\].*?)*$/i`

If your bracket doesn't need to be closed :

`/foo([;\[].+?)*$/i`

If your bracket or semicolon must not be the last part of your expression :

`/foo([;\[][^;\[]+)*$/i`

All passed the tests with [Regex planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html).

---

**Resources :**

- [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: @Activist, It's strange, can you show your code and the regex you used ?

Comment: @Colin HEBERT Added test code to OP. Just change "REGULAR EXPRESSION HERE" with the tested regexp. None of your 3 match my expected results.

Comment: Did you escaped the \ before you put it into the string ? You should have this : `$returnValue = preg_match('/foo(;.+?|\\\[.+?\\\].*?)*$/i', 'foo;');`

Comment: @Colin HEBERT Yes I know but still foo; and foo[ are labeled as bad while they are ok...

Comment: Hum, from your first post : "foo; --> bad, need something after ;" and "foo[ --> bad, need something after ]"

Comment: @Colin HEBERT LOL you are right sorry I'm a little bit sleepy right now I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
/foo($|[[;].)/i
```